# How to copy an integer value from a DefaultMutableTreeNode?

Tags: java

Could someone help me?

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode n4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Integer(4));
DefaultMutableTreeNode n7 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(9000);

DefaultMutableTreeNode a = n4;
System.out.println("a = "+a);

int b = Integer(n4);
System.out.println("b = "+b);

int c = Integer(n7);
System.out.println("c = "+c);
```

Why are b and c zero in this and only a has the value I want?

I get a = 4, b = 0 and c = 0.

Comment: `int b = Integer(n4);` does not compile. Is your code fragment right?

Comment: Code fragment? What is that?

Comment: I mean that your code does not compile.

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean, but I guess so...
What can I do?

Comment: I discovered the mistake. If I have another question I'll return here. Thx!!